# partition a table and create an index column

Tags: sql, db2

I am struggling with finding a way to partition the following table (db2):

```
ID1         ID2
---         ---
110         A
110         B
110         C
238         D
238         E
228         F 
300         G
300         H
300         I
```

I would like to create an index column that paritions by ID1 like so:

```
ID1         ID2      INDEX
---         ---      ----- 
110         A        1
110         B        1
110         C        1
238         D        2
238         E        2
228         F        2 
300         G        3 
300         H        3
300         I        3
```

Sounds simple right? I am trying to do this using the `row_number() over (parition by order by)` method.

I am trying:

```
row_number() over (parition by ID1 order by ID1)
```

however this gives me:

```
ID1         ID2      INDEX
---         ---      ----- 
110         A        1
110         B        2
110         C        3
238         D        1
238         E        2
228         F        3 
300         G        1 
300         H        2
300         I        3
```

I have tried dense_rank too but this labels every entry in INDEX as 1.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
dense_rank() over (order by id1)
```

Comment: thank you. did not lcikc that I had to remove the partition by command.